# Apexcharts Updating React state inside an event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apexcharts

so I am trying to update a boolean state using `this.setState` inside the event `dataPointMouseEnter` of a Apexcharts line graph. However, I got an error saying

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of null
    at e.filter (apexcharts.common.js:15731)
    at t.value (apexcharts.common.js:622)
    at t.value (apexcharts.common.js:662)
    at t.value (apexcharts.common.js:1095)
```

Once I have this error, the event `dataPointMouseLeave` will not trigger.

I tried to see where the exact problem is so I console logged out some statement, and it seems that the code gets this error while I have the line `this.setState({ showYAxis: true })`

Below is the code I have for this part

The `options` configuration on the events part for the graph, and the returning component

```
state = {showYAxis: false, series: []}

render() {
  const options = {
    chart: {
      events: {
        dataPointMouseEnter: this.onDataPointMouseEnter,
        dataPointMouseLeave: this.onDataPointMouseLeave,
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <Chart
      type="line"
      height="500"
      options={options}
      series={this.state.series}
    />
  );
}
```

These are the code for the two helper functions `onDataPointMouseEnter` and `onDataPointMouseLeave`

```
onDataPointMouseEnter = (event, chartContext, config) => {
  const { series, showYAxis } = this.state;

  if(series && series[config.seriesIndex].name === "myYValue") {
    this.setState({ showYAxis: true });
  }
}

onDataPointMouseLeave = (event, chartContext, config) => {
  console.log("This line should be printed in console when mouse leave data point"); // This line did not get called
}
```

When I remove the line `this.setState({ showYAxis: true })`, both functions gets called when mouse enter and mouse leave the data point. I'm trying to hide/show the y axis and the way I'm approaching this is to use `setState` to call a re-render, but now `setState` is causing an error. I would appreciate any kind of help and advise.

Comment: Hello, were you able to solve this problem because I'm facing the same issue also. Please do let me know how to overcome this issue.

Comment: @SaiPrasadNayak I don't recall I have this problem fixed, instead, I used the click event rather than onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave. However, I currently migrated the entire graph using a different library called recharts, since Im dealing with large amount of data on the graph, and apexcharts seems to be very laggy.

Comment: But how to know which data point was selected? The click event just tells that the graph was clicked. Please let me know how to do this using dataPointSelection.

Comment: So I remember I added the click events under my options configuration, and then defined the method in a helper function.
under options I had 
`const options = {
  chart: {
    events: {
      markerClick: (event, chartContext, config) => this.onMarkerClick(event, 
                                chartContext, config, myOwnArg)
    }
  }
}`

Comment: And for the helper method you could try console logging out the chartContext and the config, I think one of them gives you the selected data point information. Could be `config.dataPointIndex`

Comment: `chart: {
      events: {
        markerClick: (event: any, chartContext: any, config: any) => onMarkerClick(event, chartContext, config)
      },
    },`

The helper function :
`const onMarkerClick = (event: any, chartContext: any, config: any) => {
    console.log("handleClick")
    console.log(config, chartContext);
    const asset: string = config?.w.config.labels[config.dataPointIndex];
    console.log(asset);
  };`

Nothing is being console logged. Can you please help me out ??

Thanks :+1

Comment: That seems right, try writing it as an inline function just to test out if it console out anything. You could refer to https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/chart/events/ this page and check out the syntax of writing the event function inline.

Comment: The console logs work fine but I'm not able to handle the state in the events.
`const [state, setState] = useState(true)
 
chart: {
      events: {
        dataPointSelection:async function (event: any, chartContext: any, config: any) {
          // ...
          console.log('State', state)
          console.log(config.dataPointIndex)
          setState(!state)
          console.log('State', state)
        }
      }
    },`
The above is simple state management. But I get an error every time.
Error:`Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null`

Comment: looking at the error it seems like a value from your code has a null value, Im not sure if this dataPointSelection function is the actual cause of the error